# Web.config -> Redirect old blog URL's to new pattern

Tags: redirects

I just changed my blogging software and I have now the problem that I want to redirect my old imported blog post to the new url pattern.

My old pattern looks like:

```
www.domain.tld/blog/post/2011/03/02/my-blog-post.aspx
```

Now I want to redirect this url to:

```
www.domain.tld/blog/my-blog-post
```

How can I do this using the Web.config for a `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` message?
I just found solutions to redirect a single url, but not with dynamic placeholder.
I need to remove the year, month and day part from the url and then cut off the file extension from the post name.

I came from Blogengine.Net and switched to Funnelweb.
I have shared web space on a Windows Server 2008, so I've only FTP access.

Thank for any advice

## Solution:

Add this to the Application_BeginRequest block:

```
UriBuilder uri = new System.UriBuilder(Context.Request.Url);
Regex r = new Regex(@"^/blog/post/\d+/\d+/\d+/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)");
Match m = r.Match(uri.Path);
if (m.Success)
{
   String postName = m.Groups[1].ToString();
   uri.Path = "blog/" + postName;
   Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
   Response.AddHeader("Location", uri.ToString());
   Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Pleas let me know if you have improvements for this.

Comment: Can you add the blog and web server software you are using?  Do you have a shell access?

Comment: Sure, I added this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to do it in `web.config` (I do not know if possible or not)

But I do know a way to do this in `Global.asax`

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UriBuilder uri = new System.UriBuilder(Context.Request.Url);
        if (uri.Path == "/blog/post/2011/03/02/my-blog-post.aspx") uri.Path = "/blog/my-blog-post";
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", uri.ToString());
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

For the dynamic part, you have to use `Regex`

if (!Regex.IsMatch(url.Path, @"^/blog/post/\d+/\d+.. sorry, have to go, will come back finish later